# Convert links that contain highlighting to <a> tags

Tags: javascript

At the moment, I can convert this text:

```
Hello this is a link: http://foo.bar cheers!
```

Into `Hello this is a link: <a href="http://foo.bar">http://foo.bar</a> cheers!`

However; I use ElasticSearch to search and sometimes it highlights words within the URLs themselves; and wraps them in `<em>` tags like this:

```
Hello this is a link: http://<em>foo</em>.bar cheers!
```

Which breaks my regex and doesn't wrap the URL in an `<a>` tag properly.

Here's how I do this at the moment:

```
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i;

  text = text.replace(exp, function($1){
    return "<a href='"+$1+"'>"+$1+"</a>";
  });
```

Which results in a broken tag:

[image]

*P.S. I'd like to keep the highlighting - I know that I can just remove `em` tags then convert links.*

Comment: Why not just double check and determine if string contains <em> and therefore strip it with an additional step?

Comment: One reliable way would be to parse the HTML into a DOM, search the text representation for URLs, and find the best wrapping. Is this client-side JavaScript? Are you about to put the HTML into the current document?

Comment: @fubbe I'd like to keep the highlighting :)

Comment: Better the use the DOM it was created for these type of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[^\s]+)/ig;
var text = text.replace(exp, function($1){
    var s = $1;
    s = s.replace(/<\s*\/?\s*em\s*>/ig,'');
    return '<a href="'+s+'">'+$1+'</a>';
});
```